# Propagating traceIDs in gRPC inter service communication

Tags: microservices, grpc, trace, opentracing, grpc-go

I am working on a few gRPC micro services and using context to pass in any headers and metadata. I am using opentracing for tracing purposes and one of my gRPC services calls other gRPC service at which point I am having issues with propagating the context as it is not retaining the metadata and also traceID.
 My code is as below

```
func A(ctx context.Context) {
    metadata:=extractMetadata(ctx)
    conn := &grpc.ClientConn{}
    zipkinCtx := opentracing.SpanFromContext(ctx).Context().(gozipkin.SpanContext)
    client := pb.NewDClient(conn)

    reply, err := client.LookupProperty(metadata.NewOutgoingContext(context.Background(), metadata.New(metadata)))
}
```

In the above code I am calling the service `D` for which I had to recreate a new context with the metadata which I am ok with but I am not sure how I can propagate the tracIds to the service `D`

Comment: if you log `metadata.New(metadata)` (before you call `LookupProperty`) does it contain the trace id?

Comment: @dm03514 my traceid is not in metadata its in the ctx and I have all the metadata when I tried to log it and verify but having issues when transmitted to the other service that I am calling

Comment: Ok i think I see.  So for function A you're propagating trace information in go's context, but now you need a strategy for propagating this through GRPC calls?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing your frameworks, I think propagating this on GRPC metadata requires your server to explicitly parse the [metadata](https://grpc.io/docs/guides/concepts.html#metadata) on the receiving call.  GRPC [documentation](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/Documentation/grpc-metadata.md#retrieving-metadata-from-context) shows an example of this:

```
func (s *server) LookupProperty(ctx context.Context, in *pb.SomeRequest) (*pb.SomeResponse, err) {
    md, ok := metadata.FromIncomingContext(ctx)
    // do something with metadata
}
```

Using this the server should now have access to the Traceid; contained in ‘md’.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not absolutely sure, but it seems like `traceID` must be a custom field in GRPC Metadata. Also have a look at GRPC Interceptors that enable Opentracing support both for server and client side: https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/tree/master/tracing/opentracing. Perhaps you won't have to write your own.